# Linking a center aligned image on a landing page to another page

Tags: css, alignment, anchor, center

I'm trying to center a single clickable image on my landing page that links to another page in a password protected directory (folder2). I am able to center align the image, but I'm not able to figure out how to link the image to the page in the password protected directory the right way. When I click on the image, it takes me to a

> Bad Request - Invalid URL. HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

page.
This is how the URL in the address bar shows up:

`http://example.com/â€œ/folder2/index.htmlâ€%C2%9D`

I'm able to get to the page if I use the direct URL

http://example.com/folder2/index.html

I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me figure this out. Thanks!

This is the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    background-color: #1A928A;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div><a href=“/folder2/index.html”><img src="gliph.png"></a></div>
<style>
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

div img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `“/folder2/index.html”` should be `"/folder2/index.html"`. `""` instead of `“”`.

Comment: Thanks Xufox. I just made the change. It works as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your quote on the link is not a normal quote. “ instead of "

The second quote as well.

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid for not realizing that. The link directs as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using “ in your href instead of regular double quote: "

Please try this one

Comment: Thanks Reza. I just switched out the quotes. Works as expected now.